# Does the post about “offering a prayer to an atheist” need a "controversial topic notice"?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I'm talking about [this question](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/23532/how-can-i-offer-my-prayers-to-an-atheist-colleague-facing-a-serious-personal-sit) and it's a very controversial topic.

Would it be a good idea for a mod or CM to add the "controversial post" notice on top of the thread?

My points are the two/three sides involved:

- yes, do it, tell them
- yes, do it, don't tell
- no, do or do not, but don't tell

As for all religion-related topics, it will attract different POV (reading of the gospels / bible...) and might very easily get out of control. People can probably start arguing over "small" points.

And, from what I've read, the (too) many answers aren't that different, they "repeat" themselves.

Comment: I was thinking, we might even want to quick it out of HNQ, not because the question is bad, but because the answers aren't... really great (note: due to a lack of energy, I haven't really read the answer over there, so I have a clear view of "how bad it is")

Comment: I saw what you did there :P But on that note: It would probably be helpful if you could make some arguments about what makes it controversial for you, the things you've noticed that you think deserve a post notice. If there's enough people agreeing with those causes, it makes it easier for us moderators to see what might need one and perhaps we don't have to wait for flags/meta posts next time :)

Comment: was about to protect it after discussing here, but it's been done already :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added the notice. I've already left comments on the question with links to the answer FAQ and not arguing in comments anyways - maybe the big yellow box will be noticed more..

But, **I'd rather just take it off HNQ**. I haven't done so because I haven't run this idea past anyone yet :P and in the past some users seemed very opposed to mods doing that. (It will drop off HNQ in less than 24 hours regardless, but still would be up during most of the workday for Europe and US.)

It has garnered 23 answers total (21 undeleted + 2 deleted) so far, so I don't think there's many angles not yet covered. And it *is* generating a lot of comments.

> And, from what I've read, the (too) many answers aren't that different, they "repeat" themselves.

Agree, though I haven't had the time yet to read them all to figure out if any can be deleted as such.. Unfortunately, it's been on HNQ over the weekend when a lot of people aren't online, so there hasn't been as much active reviewing overall.

Commenting (especially with links for duplicate answers), flagging, and going through the review queue helps a lot, if you have the time/energy/spoons to do so :)

Comment: Didn't check if it had hit the HNQ, but pretty obvious when you see the traffic, votes and answers. Should have been removed from HNQ IMO. Unilaterally done by a mod wouldn't have been a problem to me :) and I think you mods could have discussed that in your "cosy private little corner". But it was over the weekend...

Comment: I don't like the idea of unilateraly removing from HNQ by **a** mod, but if several mods agree, it doesn't bother me as much. Buy I think the key to remove here is the number of answers it received. Like, if an HNQ has already gathered 15 answers, maybe it's a good sign that we should remove it.

Comment: @OldPadawan yeah, I think all the other mods were asleep when I posted this - I did drop a link in our mod room after posting this answer though! It honestly didn't occur to me earlier since this would've been the first time I press that button :) But at this point we'll probably just leave it be, since it's actually been fairly quiet so far today and will be out in a few hours anyways.

Comment: I wanted to protect it on Friday evening, but was unable to because it was not old enough. I forgot to revisit it on Saturday to add the protection. Ælis eventually protected it, but we probably could have lowered the moderation load a bit by protecting it earlier.